# React redux nested array update good practice and perfs

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-redux

I'have one simple question.

I need to update my redux state. In this state i have an array with object into it. If i need to update the valid property.

(... represent dummy values)

```
myArray: [
{valid: false, ...},
{valid: false, ...},
...
]
```

I've seen people using the .map(item, index).
I've seen people using the immutable-helpers
And people doing it with myArray[index] = {myNewObject}.

My question is what's the best in terms of performences and good practice.
The map seems ok for small array but what if i have 12000 items ? The helpers add a library and the last one seems overkill to replace a complete object to update only on attribute of it.

If you have some clue, reading, info it would help me a lot to settle this dilema.

Thank you!

Comment: You can try immer - https://github.com/immerjs/immer